CI/CD pipeline seems stuck while fetching the swift packages hosted on a private aws codeartifact repository ios
I am creating a CI/CD azure devops pipeline for my ios swift project.
The project contains the swift package dependencies.
One of the dependency is fetched from private repository hosted on aws. It is accessed via authentication token.
The commands in steps mentioned in CI pipeline are working fine if running on local machine terminal. The achieve is getting created successfully.
But the CI pipeline gets stuck while fetching the swift package. I waited for more than 15 minutes but no logs.
the yaml file:
pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-14'
steps:
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'mycertificatename.p12'
    certPwd: 'value'
    keychain: 'temp'
- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
    provProfileSecureFile: 'profilename.mobileprovision'
- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'spm | "$(Agent.OS)" | **/Package.resolved'
    path: '.build'
    restoreKeys: |
      spm | "$(Agent.OS)"
- script: 
    swift package-registry login {myrepourl}/login --token mytoken
- script: 
    swift package-registry set --global {myrepourl}
- script: |
    xcodebuild -scheme app-name -configuration Release -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' archive -archivePath $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app-name.xcarchive -verbose
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app-name.xcarchive'
    ArtifactName: 'iOSArchive'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

Logs from cmd pipeline:
User defaults from command line:
    IDEArchivePathOverride = /Users/runner/work/1/a/app-name.xcarchive
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Resolve Package Graph

Fetching from https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage.git

Creating working copy of package ‘SDWebImage’

Checking out 5.19.7 of package ‘SDWebImage’

Fetching from (my private aws repo) 

(It gets stuck here)

Any help would be highly appreciated.


Did you have the above problem in set command? 2. Please enable verbose logs, trigger the pipeline again and check if there is any detailed info.



According to this doc, swift package-registry set must be run in the project directory where you are trying to resolve the package dependency. Is the default working directory of the pipeline your project directory?



You can try to set up a self-hosted agent on the local machine where you can successfully run these commands. Then use this agent to run the pipeline and check what's the result. If it works, check what's the difference between the environment of your local machine and pipeline. If it failed, we may need some improvement in the pipeline.


not sure if its a single line you still need pipeline. but you are missing | on your lines for
- script: 
    swift package-registry login {myrepourl}/login --token mytoken
- script: 
    swift package-registry set --global {myrepourl}

while you have | for the other script lines. if its a single line i always put it next to the - script: element.
can you post logs for these two? it seems like you didnt properly login
